# Anjlab sql profiler, limit the data to only tsql and sql, statements and stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

Using anjlab sql profiler, how can I limit the captured data to only tsql and sql, statements and stored procedures?

I'm assuming that it's similar to using SQL Server 2008 profiler.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a 'new trace' you'll find Events tab.
Most of the time I check following events. They keep data minimal.

- SQLStmtCompleted
- SPstmtCompleted
- SqlfulltextQuery.

[image: Anjlab Events]

Comment: This got me on the right path.  "TextData" wasn't filling in for some of the queries until I checked "All" for the three rows, which doesn't make much sense.  Hopefully someone else will find this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

I just show the `SQLBatchCompleted` event